# How do I move SQL Server database to another computer without Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server

I have problem with my computer and I can't run any program including Management Studio.

I want to move database to another computer.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you run any program? Who is db owner?

Comment: Database only (mdf, ldf files) or the entire server?

Comment: @sepupic Database only

Comment: backup + restore, you can take a backup using sqlcmd

Comment: @supupic when i try use sqlcmd i get tis message. https://scontent.fwaw3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/28081938_1846798465390561_1806656689_o.jpg?oh=3ba8e360f41f5a98690b8a85eafb7fa1&oe=5A86446E . Sorry for phone picture not screenshot.

Comment: You said you can't run any program - does that include Powershell?

Comment: @Scott Hodgin I can run it.

Answer (score 1):

SSMS does nothing else than send SQL commands to the server.

You can use Sqlcmd or any other way to submit your own commands.

- Detach database
- Copy files
- Attach database.

Read up on the proper sql commands and then issue them.

Comment: Backup/restore is much safer than detach/attach

Comment: But then you better remember to block any updates on the original database before starting the backup. Agree, though - it possiblöy also is faster due to smaller file sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If `POWERSHELL` is still operational on the source computer:

- You can try to run the native SQL Server Powershell module
  [Backup-SqlDatabase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/backup-sqldatabase?view=sqlserver-ps) which would back up the database(s) to their default backup
  directory.

  `Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "Computer\Instance" -Database "MainDB"`

Or

- Download the [Dbatools Powershell Module](https://dbatools.io/) and
  run
  [Backup-DbaDatabase](https://dbatools.io/functions/backup-dbadatabase/)

  `Backup-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance Server1 -Databases HR, Finance`

Then, copy the backup files to the target computer and restore.

---

If you simply cannot take a backup of the database(s), you will probably have to resort to stopping the SQL Server service and copying the underlying mdf, ndf and ldf files from the source computer to the target computer.

Comment: You can do it even easier with dbatools - `Copy-DbaDatabase`  - as long as you have a network share that's accessible by both instances.